# WaitForSingleObject and Deadlock

Tags: windows, synchronization, deadlock, waitforsingleobject

I read an article about synchronization on Windows.

[Locks, Deadlocks, and Synchronization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810047.aspx#locks__topic13)

It is said that normal kernel-mode APC delivery should be disabled by calling `KeEnterCriticalRegion()` before calling `KeWaitXxx()` to avoid deadlock.

I understood that. But AFAIK, there is no API like `KeEnterCriticalRegion()` for user application so `WaitForSingleObject()` seems to be unsafe for deadlock.

Otherwise, is `KeEnterCriticalRegion()` internally called in `WaitForSingleObject()` call?

Comment: You got pretty lost, that article only applies to device driver development.  It has absolutely nothing to do with a user application.